# Ipad to tv connection

Tags: ipad

I have internet plan on my ipad just like my iphone. How can I hook my ipad to my tv using the internet instead of wifi?  I want to watch movies from my ipad on my tv.

Comment: Ok, Internet is the system. The WiFi is the method or the technology to send/receive Internet. depending on your iPhone type and your TV type you could watch the movies from your Internet account on your TV. So what are your devices ?

Comment: Be sure to edit in the connectors that the TV allows. We can't guess what TV you have which makes it hard to answer this usefully...

Answer (score 1):

Best way to connect your iPad to your TV is with an Apple TV. They have HDMI and optical audio connections and connect to your home network via Ethernet or Wifi. When used in conjunction with Home Sharing and iTunes, it can also access the media and your home computers.  Apple TV cost $100 new but can be bought used for less. The second generation Apple TV support 720p video and the third generation supports 1080p.